# What is the way(s) ? Inserting DB in every 6 hours

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a problem and confused a little bit. I made some research in stackoverflow but cannot reach the exact solution.

My problem is that : I retrieve some datas from Google Analytics but this method is too slow.What i want to do is that i want to retrieve datas from Google each 6 hours and inserting them into DB then users can have datas on my site faster because i will take datas from DB.

In my research, i find some solutions like cron and memcached, but is there any way to do in php with some functions?

In phpp manual, i recognize some function like `time()` . Can i do that with time() function ?

Comment: You can use PHP to make the script and repeat it every 6 hours. You will have to code the application and then run it and then it can loop. A cron task is better. However I do not think Google Analytics has an API for this? I would try GetClicky - it is so much better and real-time.

Comment: The problem with that is that the php script still needs executing.  If you put it within a cron job then it will be done every 6 hours regardless of user traffic, and won't result in any users having a slow request due to them being the one that triggers the analytics refresh.  TLDR version, I'd do it as a cron job triggering a PHP script or similar which will in turn retrieve/process the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it in this way. You store data from google in your DB, but adds one more field - like `last_update_time` and put there the time you have got it from google. When next time user is getting data from your DB, you need to check the difference between `last_update_time` and current time. Then if it is bigger than 6 hour, so you grab new data from google and refresh it in you DB, as the `last_update_time`.
This will allow you not to use cron.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Possible the best way is cron.

Comment: This will also expose the slow and long running nature of this cache refresh process to the user so they will see a slow running website. It is a valid suggestion, but it does need this shortfall pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is best solved with a cronjob. PHP does not have a built in system for scheduling jobs.

If your host does not allow cronjobs then you could use a hosted service like those listed on [Chris Dukes' site](http://chrisduke.tv/147/review-web-hosted-cron-job-schedulers):

- [Web Service Scheduler](http://www.wsscheduler.com/)
- [WebBasedCron](http://www.webbasedcron.com/) - which he declares his favourite

In the CMS I develop for work there is a Google Analytics graph and we use a cronjob that runs every night to grab the latest stats. I just cache them as JSON to a file rather than putting it into a database. We then render it using [jQuery flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).